# CSS and jQuery slider height/positioning question

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

[THIS IS THE TEST SITE](http://174.120.239.48/~peakperf/?page_id=203).

If you look at the example above the slider on the right has 2 images.  The first one is smaller than the second. The second is around 500px high. What I'm looking to do is expand the slider vertically depending on the height of the images inside.

I believe the js is setting the height of the image when it is called from the server and I can't find a way to override it with the CSS.

Any help would be very appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: That just sounds like a bad idea to me, because you'll be causing the page below to move up and down - what if someone's trying to click a link?

Comment: @wilwaldon - The two images look exactly the same size to me.

Comment: @crimson_penguin. I just take orders from the creative director. I agree it's a bad idea and brought it up but there's nothing I can do at this point.

Comment: @jmort. sorry, forgot to upload the other image. Uploaded now.

Comment: Both images are **exactly** the same size, the cropped text on one of the images is not the JavaScript, but the image itself.

Comment: @Wilwaldon - Unless you're going to make the height of the featuredworkfocus DIV large enough to hold the larger image and be a fixed height.  I don't recommend this.  You need a new Creative Director if he's okay with making the bottom shift up and down.  Sorry, I can't answer this question in good faith.

Comment: @jmort. Totally understand man. And I totally agree. Thanks for tryin though!

Answer (score 1):

First of all what crimson_penguin said it's true. You have to define beforehand a containers height and make sure that the images inside don't exceed that heigh.

Look for this lines in the cycle plugin:

```
if (opts.fit && opts.height && opts.height != 'auto')

    $slides.height(opts.height);
```

These tells the plugin to stretch the image. Below that there are the lines that stretch the container. Fooling around with that will solve your problem.